# Session timeout warning on multi-page / tab asp website

Tags: javascript, asp.net

We have an asp.net website which is used as a point of sale system by staff in a heating supplies comp[any. It uses a menu that is always open and opens new pages for each selection made by the user, so that they can switch between the open pages as necessary. The users often spend time dealing with customers (eg giving advice, showing them products etc) or waiting for the next customer, but they then need the website to continue with their current selections on all open pages. At the moment, the website sometimes times out in these idle periods and they lose all the selections they had set up - or even a part-finished order form. We don't want to set the timeout period to a very long time as this would compromise security, but we would like to give a warning a few minutes before timeout, so that the user can click a "Continue" button that would restart the session timer. Ideally, this warning and continue button would be on a new page/tab to avoid losing settings on the current page.

We have tried a javascript timer and various other methods (eg Telerik notification control) but we either get a new warning page opening for every page the user has open (if we put the timer on the master page), or - if we put the timer on just one page - the user might be on a different page and does not see the warning.

Can anyone suggest a method that would work better?

Comment: I'm not sure this requirement even makes any sense, since the Session Timeout is a SLIDING expiration value. In other words, when a user requests a page, their session timeout automatically gets extended.

Comment: We reset the session timer every time the user uses ANY of the open pages. It would only allow a timeout if there was no activity on ANY page. But at this point, there might be several pages open and we want to warn the user before the session is timed out and he loses all the data he has entered on these pages. I do not understand your point.